# Extract data using SQL, analyse and write back to SQL table

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am a newbie to SAS Base, and I am struggling to create a simple program that extracts data from a table on my database, runs e.g. PROC MEANS, and writes the data back to the table.

I know how to use PROC SQL (read and update tables) and PROC MEANS, but I can't figure out how to combine the steps.

```
PROC SQL;
SELECT make,model,type,invoice,horsepower
FROM 
SASHELP.CARS
;
QUIT;
PROC Means;
RUN;
```

What I want to accomplish is create an additional column in the dataset with e.g. the mean of the horsepower.. and in the end I want to write that computed column to the table on the database.

---

Edit
What I was looking for is this:

```
PROC SQL;
create table want as 
select make,model,type,invoice,horsepower
, mean(horsepower) as mean_horsepower
from sashelp.cars
;
QUIT;
PROC MEANS DATA=want;
RUN;
```

Comment: Show the steps you tried.  Are you just asking how to have PROC MEANS write out the results to a dataset?  If so look at the OUTPUT statement.

Comment: Hi Tom. I updated the question with additional info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS makes this very easy to do with SQL since it will automatically remerge summary statistics back to detailed records.

```
create table want as 
  select make,model,type,invoice,horsepower
       , mean(horsepower) as mean_horsepower
  from sashelp.cars
;
```

Or using normal SAS code.

```
proc means data=sashelp.cars nway noprint ;
  var horsepower ;
  output out=mean_horsepower mean=mean_horsepower ;
run;
data want ;
  set sashelp.cars ;
  if _n_=1 then set mean_horsepower (keep=mean_horsepower);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom. So it's not possible to pass the results of an SQL query directly to a PROC statement? Or would I need to "create table A" and then do a data step where I do data B; set A?

Comment: Create a table. If you need to save space then create a view and access the view instead.

Comment: No, it's not possible to pass the results of query to a proc statement, you do this by creating a table and passing the table to the proc. When you do this, you should always reference the table in the DATA = portion of the PROC statement.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. I am still a bit confused though.. Should I create the SAS table from the PROC SQL like this?

create table testA as 
  select make,model,type,invoice,horsepower
       , mean(horsepower) as mean_horsepower
  from sashelp.cars
;
data testB ;
  set tableA ;
run;

Comment: Your last step is just making another copy of the same data. Why would you do that?